# convert crosstab to columns without using pandas in python

Tags: python, csv, crosstab

How do I convert the crosstab data from the input file mentioned below into columns based on the input list without using pandas?

**Input list**

`[A,B,C]`

**Input data file**

Labels A,B,C are only for representation, original file only has the numeric values.
We can ignore the colums XX & YY based on the length of the input list

```
  A B C XX YY
A 0 2 3 4  8
B 4 0 6 4  8
C 7 8 0 5  8
```

**Output** (Output needs to have labels)

```
A A 0
A B 2
A C 3
B A 4
B B 0
B C 6
C A 7
C B 8
C C 0
```

The labels need to be present in the output file even though its present in the input file, hence I have mentioned its representation in the output file.

NB: In reality the labels are sorted city names without duplicates in ascending order & not single alphabets like A or B.

Unfortunately this would have been easier if I could install pandas on the server & use unstack(), but installations aren't allowed on this old server right now. 
This is on python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Considering you tagged the post `csv`, I'm assuming the actual input data is a .csv file, without header as you indicated.

So example data would look like:

```
0,2,3,4,8
4,0,6,4,8
7,8,0,5,8
```

If the labels are provided as a list, matching the order of the columns and rows (i.e. `['A', 'B', 'C']` this would turn the example output into:

```
'A','A',0
'A','B',2
'A','C',3
'B','A',4
etc.
```

Note that this implies the number of rows and columns in the file cannot exceed the number of labels provided.

You indicate that the columns you label 'XX' and 'YY' are to be ignored, but you don't indicate how that's supposed to be communicated, but you do mention the length of the input is determining it, so I assume this means 'everything after column n can be ignored'.

This is a simple implementation:

```
from csv import reader


def unstack_csv(fn, columns, labels):
    with open(fn) as f:
        cr = reader(f)
        row = 0
        for line in cr:
            col = 0
            for x in line[:columns]:
                yield labels[row], labels[col], x
                col += 1
            row += 1


print(list(unstack_csv('unstack.csv', 3, ['A', 'B', 'C'])))
```

or if you like it short and sweet:

```
from csv import reader

with open('unstack.csv') as f:
    content = reader(f)
    labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    print([(labels[row], labels[col], x)
           for row, data in enumerate(content)
           for col, x in enumerate(data) if col < 3])
```

(I'm also assuming using numpy is out, for the same reason as pandas, but that stuff like `csv` is in, since it's a standard library)

If you don't want to provide the labels explicitly, but just want them generated, you could do something like:

```
def label(n):
    r = n // 26
    c = chr(65 + (n % 26))
    if r > 0:
        return label(r-1)+c
    else:
        return c
```

And then of course just remove the `labels` from the examples and replace with calls to `label(col)` and `label(row)`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.
The labels `'XX' and 'YY'` need to ignored based on the length of the input list `[A,B,C]`. So yes everything after the nth column can be ignored.

Comment: the output labels need to be derived from the input list `[A,B,C']` , that's why I have mentioned the labels even thought its not available the actual `input file`.
Could you please let me know how to add the labels dynamically in that case?

Comment: I updated the code to use labels instead of indices, not sure if that matches what you mean by 'dynamically' though. You could of course define a function that makes up the labels as it goes along, alphanumerically (i.e. 1>'A', 2>'B', .., 26>'Z', 27>'AA', etc.)

Comment: I've added a function like that, as a bonus ;-)

Comment: I am sorry the labels aren't really alphabets. I should have mentioned that. Apologies.  In reality they are sorted city names without duplicates in ascending order.

Comment: It's generally helpful to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example to get the answer you really need :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: All the same, I think my answer still answers your question, you just have no need for the function at the end.

Comment: Thanks for helping out & for your patience. :) Apologies, since I am new to Stackoverflow. I think I can modify the labels function to return the needed value for the actual label names

Comment: Note that the examples above it already include a list of labels `['A', 'B', 'C']`, so you can just replace that list with the list of city names.